# Convert JSON results (in html) into table with two columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I'm trying to load the JSON results into two columns in a table:
Here is my HTML code:

```
<script>

        var i;

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "http://localhost/ion/ver_comp.php",
                async : true,
                success : function(datos) {
                    var dataJson = eval(datos);

                    for ( i in dataJson) {

                        $("#content").append("<img src='"+dataJson[i].imagen+"' />");

                    }

                },
                error : function(obj, error, objError) {
                    //avisar que ocurrió un error
                    alert("ERROR DE CONEXION CON SERVIDOR");
                }

            });

        });

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

            <div id="content">
            </div> <!-- /content -->


    </body>
```

And here is my JSON code (from the PHP script):

```
[
    {
        "cod": "1",
        "nombre": "Target HR",
        "imagen": "http://i.imgur.com/DFLF20G.png"
    },
    {
        "cod": "2",
        "nombre": "BCP",
        "imagen": "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT3JhpDOH-cK-d2QF3RflbSc6dgb1ELCblX6UWiX63S3OzKST0r"
    },
    {
        "cod": "3",
        "nombre": "Gloria",
        "imagen": "http://cdnimg.perulactea.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/Gloria1.JPG"
    },
    {
        "cod": "4",
        "nombre": "Cristal",
        "imagen": "http://filmsperu.pe/New/Images/Noticias/content/CRISTAL_YR_15_06_2011/670x02.gif"
    }
]
```

The problem is displaying the 'images' (from the json) in two columns.
I just don't know how to...

Greetings..

Comment: You would create columns in CSS the same way as if the source wasn't JSON. May I ask why that is relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

This will add a `div` (which breaks a line cuz it's a block element) (as opposed to img which is inline element)

```
 for (var i=0;i<dataJson.length;i++) {

                        if (i%2==0) $("#content").append("<div/>")
                        $("#content").append("<img src='"+dataJson[i].imagen+"' />");
                    }
```

This will look like 2 columns.

p.s. If youre talking about 2 columns as like in a table,  that's another thing. ( code on the way) :

if you have table :

```
 var dataJson = eval(t);

var row=0;
   for (var i=0;i<dataJson.length;i++)
   {
     row=Math.round((0.4)*Math.floor(i)); //row number trick is here. 

     $("table tr").eq(row).find("td").eq(i%2).append("<img src='"+dataJson[i].imagen+"' width='100'/>");
     }
```

**http://jsbin.com/arojaw/3/edit**

[image]

Comment: @JhonatanSandoval np.

Answer (score 0):

Try: 
   this will create a table list with two columns

```
 var tbl = '<table>'
     $.each(datas,function(i,val){
          if(i%2==0)tbl += '<tr>';      
          tbl += '<td><img src="'+val.imagen+'">'+val.nombre+'</td>';       
          if(i%2==1)tbl += '</tr>';
    });
    if(datas.length%2==1)tbl += '</tr>';//safely closes the tr
    tbl += '</table>';
    $("#content").html(tbl);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$("#content").append("<table>");
for (var i=0;i<dataJson.length;i++)
{
     $("#content").append("<tr><td><img src='"+dataJson[i].imagen+"' /></td></tr>");
}
$("#content").append("</table>");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
            $("#content").append("<table>");
            for (i in dataJson) {
                if(i % 2 == 0) {
                    $("#content").append("<tr>"); 
                    $("#content").append("<td><img src='"+dataJson[i].imagen+"' width='100px' height='100px'/></td>"); 
                } else {
                    $("#content").append("<td><img src='"+dataJson[i].imagen+"' width='100px' height='100px'/></td>"); 
                    $("#content").append("</tr>"); 
                }
            } 
            $("#content").append("</table>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly of all I'm not sure why you want to use tables for this display, since a simple floated div collection would yield the same result with much less markup.

Secondly I'd definitely recommend thinking about a templating engine, which helps you to keep Logic and Presentation separated. As an example you can use JS Templaters like Mustache or Handlebars.

[Here is a fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Uhqzj/1/) showing how this may be done.